# парсинг на Python, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, парсер

надо забрать текс 111 из тега

```
<div class="pagination">
<strong class="current">1</strong>
<a class="next pagination-link" href="/strana-2/">
<span class="sr-only">Další strana</span>
</a>
<a href="/psi/strana-111/">111</a>
</div>
```

пишу так

```
pagination = soup.find('div', class_="pagination").find('a', {'href':re.compile('\/[a-z]*\/strana-.\d*\/')}).get_text()
```

выдает ошибку

```
 pagination = soup.find('div', class_="pagination").find('a', {'href':re.compile('\/[a-z]*\/strana-.\d*\/')}).get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Что делаю не так, как исправить?

Comment: `\/[a-z]*\/` лишнее `\/` поэтому не находит `a` и возвращает `None`, у которого вы пытаетесь вызвать `get_text()`

Comment: не дописал слеш в теге, исходный такой <a href="/psi/strana-111/">111</a>, поэтому думаю не лишний

Comment: Я бы так сделал `re.compile(r'/[a-z]*/strana-.\d*/')`. Вообще, я попробовал ваш пример и ошибки не было (python 3.10). Скорее всего, у вас другой случай. Мб текст в href другой?

Comment: я вначале слеш забыл поставить первый, потом после вашего коммента увидел ошибку и и справил, попробую ваш вариант. Но пока я решил другим вариантом soup.find('div', class_="pagination").find_all('a')[-1].get_text() Тупо взял последний тег <a> и из него текст